# T-SQL INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger: update all columns with counterpart column from INSERTED table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

If you're going to enforce business rules in an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger, rolling transactions back if a rule is violated, you have to constantly maintain that trigger whenever a new column is added to the table, and include the newly added column in your update statement:

```
UPDATE T
SET A = INSERTED.A,
    B = INSERTED.B,
    NewColumn = INSERTED.NewColumn
FROM MyTable T
INNER JOIN INSERTED ON T.id = INSERTED.id;
```

Is there some "syntactic sugar" that would permit something  along these lines:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.* = INSERTED.*     -- <<==
FROM MyTable T
INNER JOIN INSERTED ON T.id = INSERTED.id;
```

so that such maintenance would not be necessary?

Comment: Nope. If you want to update a column you have to reference it explicitly. The only way I could see something like that would be if you did the update in dynamic sql after referencing sys.columns. But I don't think I would recommend something like that.

Comment: If you're going to enforce business rules in an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger, you are doing it wrong. The database should not be responsible for business rules. That's the job of the application.

Comment: @Zohar Peled:  There are two schools of thought on that.. There are MANY applications, and the goal is to prevent any one of them from screwing things up. An intelligent database can protect itself. No need to cede that responsibility to another tier.

Comment: @Tim Well, some things are just better handled by code...

Comment: It is possible to do a delete and then an insert. Identity fields would cause issues though.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Agreed that procedures with conditional logic and control structures are required. But T-SQL is available.